# how to take the count based on first week and second and third week and fourth week

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table name (**task**), here i want take the **count** like how many registration happend in first and how many registration happend in second how how can do this , i am the new persion of mysql and PHP .

```
id              name                   t_created_on
1               Kani                   2017-03-03 12:45:18
2               yuvi                   2017-03-04 12:45:18  
3               Mahesh                 2017-03-11 12:45:18
```

> Here i am using this format   **date("Y-m-d h:i:s")**

Bassed on my database first week 2 registration and second week is 1.

> Expected results:

First Week count : 2

Second week count : 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
SELECT count(*) as records FROM tbl
WHERE t_created_on >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND t_created_on < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

2.

```
SELECT count(*) as weekrecord  FROM tb1
WHERE 
WEEK (date) = WEEK( current_date ) -1 AND YEAR( date) = YEAR( current_date );
```

note: WEEK( current_date ) -1: number indicates number of week.

Comment: How to display first week count & second week count ?

Comment: 2. ans 1 indicate one week back . if you increase  by then it will give two week back and so on

Comment: Mr Pramod Kharade your second answer is working fine, i have one more answer i want to display month wish means what i want to do please update your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WEEK(t_created_on) as week, count(*) as count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY WEEK(t_created_on)
ORDER BY WEEK(t_created_on);
```

Comment: How to display first week count & second week count ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT count(*) as weekrecord, MONTH(current_date) as monthwise
 FROM tb1
    WHERE 
        WEEK (date) = WEEK( current_date ) -1
        AND YEAR( date) = YEAR( current_date );
```

Comment: @Subikshan M this ans for month wise separation. if answer is working for you then please upvote it.

Comment: In my database i have total 7 records, from this query weekrecord is showing correct but month record is showing wrong , this query return the results like weekrecord=4 , and monthwise  = 3, actual results  month wise record is 7